# C++ unexpected syntax errors

Tags: c++, constructor, include, friend, ostream

Ok I have updated the code:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include<cstdlib>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template < typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : size(10), index(0) { vec = new T[10]; };
    MyClass(int i) : size(i), index(0) { vec = new T[i]; };
    friend bool Add(T i);
    virtual ~MyClass();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const T& obj);

private:
    T * vec;
    int size;
    int index;
};
template <typename T>
virtual MyClass<T>::~MyClass()
{
    delete[] vec;
}
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyClass<T>& obj){
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        out << obj[i] << " ";
    out << endl;
}
template <typename T>
bool MyClass<T>::Add(T i){
    if (size == index){
        size *= 2;
        realloc(vec, size);
    }
    vec[index++] = i;
}
#endif // !VECTOR_H
```

Error list:
Error   1   error C2039: 'add' : is not a member of 'MyClass'    c:\users\mihaibogdan\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\dashit\dashit\header.h   41

Comment: Try using `std::ostream&` instead of `ostream&`.

Comment: First of all, *what* errors are you getting? Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log. Secondly, which line is line 13? Please mark it out some way, like a comment or something.

Comment: Maybe you'll like [Clang's errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/072554d676124b1b) better. On a side note, there are a ton of errors in here.

Comment: Note that your header guards don't work, since you don't actually `#define VECTOR_H`.

Comment: `vec = new T[i]` needs a semicolon after it, like your compiler is telling you.

Comment: if you use something like function(int i){ i++}; u need to place ';' even thou its a single command?

Comment: @Mihai: Yes. Try it if you don't believe it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use qualified names

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const T& obj);
```

Standard C++ names are declared in name space `std`.

Otherwise the compiler looks up unqualified name `ostream` in the global name space where it is not of course declared.